# CSS and Internet Explorer incompatibility

Tags: css

I'm really struggling with a page that looks great in Firefox and Chrome, but looks like absolute crap in IE.

I am clearly missing something, but I am not extremely familiar with the compatibility issues between browsers when it comes to CSS.  Can anyone give me a tip?

[Page with the issue](http://www.talesfromcubeland.com/Tale.jsp?Key=34&Title=The%20True%20Customer%20ServiceShorten%20Links%20Here).

the index page looks fine! which really is throwing me for a loop...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your page has no doctype, so IE is falling back to quirks mode.

Try adding this above the html tag:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

Comment: You're right! It was the doctype!!!  I will check your answer (but I have to wait another 10 minutes!

Comment: what does firefox and chrome does when they don't have doctype.

Comment: Firefox and Chrome always display pages according to the spec. Only ie has a special mode to allow you to re-enable all the bugs that were in ie6 :S

Comment: nice catch , good question good answer , i think i never ran into this problem as i always use visual studio to create the pages and it does it properly

Answer (score 2):

First of all this is a malformed HTML `<head> <body> </head> <body>`, make it `<html> <head> <scripts .../></head> <body> </body></html>`. This will make your second page look like first one.

I added an XHTML DTD to fix the center alignment
`<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">`. This will make your first page also look more like chrome and Firefox.

Finally you are using HTML5 tags `<header>` and `<nav>`. HTML5 is not  fully supported in IE, firefox chrome supports it partially. I would rather be skeptical in using them now or at least test in all browsers. Although I see you have added one js for simulating HTML5 in IE. Put that js before body. But its interesting how it simulates HTML5 :).

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a CSS reset? This is the CSS reset I'm using: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ but there are other variations that are useful too.

Will help fix most browser incompatibility issues. ;)